# undefined reference to `SHA1' at line

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I try to compile a library on linux. this libary uses `<openssl/sha.h>` library. I have included this library in source file. After that, i use flag `-lssl` and flag `-lcrypto` to compile this project. So here is my command :

`gcc -g -Wall -lssl -lcrypto -o bt_client file_a.c file_b.c`

But I meet error :

```
undefined reference to `SHA1' at line 130
```

Code at line 130 is :

```
SHA1((unsigned char *) null_padded_name, 20, (unsigned char *)name_sha1);
```

Do I miss something ? Please correct me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you link your application, the linker looks for dependencies in the order you give them on the command line.

So if you add a library (like `-lssl`) before the source/object file that depends on that library, the linker will not find any dependencies and ignore the library.

This means that you must always put libraries last on the command line.

Comment: This has the interesting capability of allowing you to override/wrap calls by placing your wrapper code between the using code and the actual library code.

Comment: Not true.  I always put my libraries first and my .C and .o files last.  (No good reason, copy an old makefile to create the next one.)  I'm using g++ on Linux.  The answers below helped me.  I was saying "-lssl".  I needed to add "-lcrypto".

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
gcc -g -Wall -o bt_client file_a.c file_b.c -lssl -lcrypto
```

If you are sure that symbol `SHA1` exists in `libssl.so` or `libcrypto.so`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide -lssl and -lcrypto at the end of the command line:

```
gcc -g -Wall -o bt_client file_a.c file_b.c -lssl -lcrypto
```